# Why does the folloing code throw an illegal instruction exception in visual studio 2010 (x64 application)?

Tags: c++, loops, exception

I have a 2D game where every position is build with 3 coordinates (x = width, y = height, and floor = z)

I tried to write a function that throws me a list of all floor tiles from the start to the end position.

And the following code is throwing an 'illegal instruction' - exception. Im puzzled:

```
std::list<Tile*> Map::getTileArea(Position positionStart, Position positionEnd)
{
    std::list<Tile*> tileAreaList;

if(positionStart.x > positionEnd.x) {
    std::swap(positionStart.x, positionEnd.x);
}

if(positionStart.y > positionEnd.y) {
    std::swap(positionStart.y, positionEnd.y);
}

if(positionStart.z > positionEnd.z) {
    std::swap(positionStart.z, positionEnd.z);
}


    for(int _x = positionStart.x; _x < positionEnd.x; _x++) {//<-Exception occurs here.
        //Procedurestepping told me that but I cannot find an explanation for this.
        for(int _y = positionStart.y; _y < positionEnd.y; _y++) {
        for(int _z = positionStart.z; _z < positionEnd.z; _z++) {
            Tile* tile = getTileByPosition(Position(_x, _y, _z));
            if(tile != NULL) {
                tileAreaList.push_back(tile);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tileAreaList;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: Is the area (of tiles) an even square? where max x == max y == max z?

Comment: for(int _x = positionStart.x; _x < positionEnd.x; _x++) { 
<- The exception occurs in this line.

It loops a little time through Y and Z layer and then if it comes to call first loop again, exception pops out.

Comment: You do std::swap() on x coordinate in all three if-cases. Could it be that y and z isn't swaped properly?

Comment: It's probably not related to the problem, but you're always swapping `x` even after comparing `y` or `z`; I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just see the x swapping, I fixed it! My bad. 
But its not fixing the exception. =(

Comment: @user1356103: Yes, the area can be an even square or better cube with possible multiple layers. Some tiles can be ignored if not set with the mapeditor thou, but thats not related to the loop problem.

Comment: What is `Position`? Is it just a simple struct with x, y and z properties?

Comment: What does `getTileByPosition` look like? It's the only thing inside the loop that could possibly break anything, alongside the `Position` constructors & destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a cut paste error:

```
if(positionStart.y > positionEnd.y) {
     std::swap(positionStart.y, positionEnd.y);
}

if(positionStart.z > positionEnd.z) {
    std::swap(positionStart.z, positionEnd.z);
}
```

Comment: I always wonder - What is "cut-paste" error? How can this happen?

Comment: Typically happens when you copy the same code multiple times and then only partially modify it, leaving broken logic.

Comment: I already fixed that but it didnt help to fix the exception.

Comment: whats the x,y,z types within the Position class?

Comment: @tillerstarr: You leave no hope) - Without "cut-pasting" parts of code there is high probability to introduce typos and with "cut-paste" we are left with "broken logic". In ideal world we don't have to ask people to cut-paste only once.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you shouldn't cut and paste... its just a common error.  Happens all the time.

Comment: "Common error. Happens all the time" - No. Most of the time people try to cover their "common errors" saying it is because of multiple "cut-paste" operations. Btw, categorizing error as "common" doesn't make its consequences "lighter".